# How to train neural network on large training set and small memory

Tags: machine-learning, gpu, neural-network, gpgpu, training-data

I write my own neural net library with backpropagation using gpu computing.
Want to make it universal, that I dont must check if the training set fits to the gpu memory.

How do you train a neural net, when the training set is too large to fit in gpu memory?
I assume that it fits in RAM of the host.

Must I do the train iteration on the firts piece, then deallocate it on the device and send the second piece to the device and train on that, so on ...
And then sum up the gradient results.

Is it not too slow, when i must push all the data trough the PCIe bus?
Have you a better idea?

Comment: Maybe you can getan idea by looking this [code](http://gpumlib.sourceforge.net/) about neural nets.

Comment: It is a good library. I did not find this one, when I searched GPU machine learning on the internet. I've studied the code a little, but there is not an mechanism that takes care about the memory issue. In backpropagation, they are passing an `HostMatrix` of train inputs to the training algorithm and that just resize the `DeviceMatrix` and copying straight to the device. If it does not return `cudaSuccess` then it creates an empty matrix. But thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use [minibatch gradient descent](http://ufldl.stanford.edu/tutorial/index.php/Optimization%3a_Stochastic_Gradient_Descent): in a loop,

- send a batch of samples to the GPU
- compute error, backprop gradient
- adjust parameters.

Repeat this loop several times until the network converges.

This is not exactly equivalent to the naive batch learning algorithm (batch gradient descent): in fact it usually converges *faster* than batch learning. It helps if you randomly shuffle the samples before each training loop. So you still have the memory transfers, but you don't need as many iterations and the algorithm will run faster.

Comment: That is good, but I want to minimize the data transfers trough the PCIe, and not push the data (even a small batch) after each iteration.

Comment: If your data all fit on the GPU, you should put it all there in one go and then use minibatches (faster convergence than computing the gradient on the whole dataset). If it doesn't, you're stuck with the transfers anyway, and you should *still* use minibatches (don't compute a bit of the gradient at a time and sum to get overall: compute the gradient on a small batch and then take a step based on that partial gradient)